# Broadband gets disconnected after some service fails

Tags: windows, windows-xp, broadband, windows-services

I have Windows XP installed on my computer which has some issues due to which "DHCP Client" service often fails, earlier I could rectify this just by starting the service, however recently I switched to broadband connection (from earlier "WiMax" one), and now even after I restart the service (after it stops), connection doesn't work and the only resort for me is to restart my computer. I suspect it might be due to some other service, but I am not able to find it.

Any help will be most appreciated

Comment: run command prompt with admin rights and run "sfc /scannow" to ensure that system files are okay.

Comment: @tumchaaditya Thanks I will try, just a question though how do I run command prompt on XP with admin rights I thought it was just for Win 7

Comment: If you are using an account with admin privileges(which is usually the case with home PCs), run it directly from "Run".

Comment: @tumchaaditya OK I ran the command, I am getting a prompt "Files that are required for Windows to run properly must be copied to the DLL Cache. Insert your Win XP SP2 CD now"

Comment: well then do so.. :)

sfc(system file checker) utility checks all system files for any discrepancy and replaces any faulty file. For that, it is gonna require original files. btw, which broadband do you use? is it MTNL/BSNL?

Comment: @tumchaaditya ... About that, I dont have the CDs neither I can get them for reasons best left unsaid :-(. I am using BSNL now.

Comment: I suppose i can help. But, we cant chat along here, in comments according to site rules. So, i'll move this to SU chat. But, i cant access chat right now. I'll reach back to you when I get back home.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3575/discussion-between-tumchaaditya-and-gaurav)